# switch-case with a string and enum in java

Tags: java, android, string, enums, switch-statement

I wanted to check a string with the value of enum in java using switch-case, so I did like this:

```
public enum DemoEnumType {

    ALL(""),
    TOP("acb"),
    BOTTOM("def");

    private String code;

    DemoEnumType(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String code() {
        return this.code;
    }


}
```

and when I run this code it throws an exception:

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DemoEnumType typeValue = DemoEnumType.valueOf("acb");
        
        switch (typeValue){
            case ALL:
                System.out.print("match");
            case BOTTOM:
                System.out.print("match");
            case TOP:
                System.out.print("match");
        }

    }
}
```

**Exeption:**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant package.DemoEnumType.acb.

Comment: What does your bottom sentence mean? Could you please translate it to English? What exception is thrown? Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: yep. I have corrected the post and that is an exception

Comment: also: don't forget to use break; statements

Answer (score 2):

```java
DemoEnumType typeValue = DemoEnumType.valueOf("acb");
```

No enum element exists with the value `acb`. `Enum#valueOf` will throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if no element exists with the given `name`. You need to use `ALL`, `BOTTOM`, or `TOP`.

```java
DemoEnumType type = DemoEnumType.valueOf("ALL");
```

Alternatively, you could use a Map of String to DemoEnumType for O(1) lookup and use the values you've provided.

```java
Map<String, DemoEnumType> valueToType = Stream.of(DemoEnumType.values())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(DemoEnumType::code, Function.identity());

DemoEnumType type = valueToType.get("abc");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Enum members are ALL, TOP and BOTTOM, not the string values. you can only pass then to valueOf().

To use the string values you can create a method in your Enum that receives a String and returns the appropriate Enum